# How to cache lookup for a property of objects in a list?

Tags: java

I have a list with entries, as follows:

```
public class Entry {
   private String origin;
   private String destination;
   private Date date;
}
```

I want to be able so search for each of those properties independently, and show the belonging entries accordingly.

Example:

```
#origin, destination, date
berlin, newyork, 2017-10-10
berlin, london, 2017-10-10
sydney, barcelona, 2017-10-10
```

- If someone searches for "origin=berlin", I want to show: `destinations=newyork, london; date=2017-10-10`.
- Search for `destination=london` should result in `origin=berlin; date=2017-10-10`.
- Likewise search for `date=2017-10-10` should show `origin=berlin, sydney; destination=newyork, london, barcelona`.

Question: how can I implement this inmemory (I cannot use eg a `mysql` database)?

Of course I could iterate all of my objects every time a search request comes in, eg:

```
List destinations;
List dates;

for (entry : entries) {
  if (entry.origin.equals("berlin")) {
    destinations.add(entry.destination);
    dates.add(entry.date);
  }
}
```

But I'd prefer a cached solution, so I won't have to recreate them on each search (and also to save time).

Sidenote: the `Entry` list is a view of a `SELECT DISTINCT origin, dest, date from table`. As I don't want to query the database on each search request.

Comment: how is someone whit such a gut rep. doing this: ***entry.origin == "berlin"***....

Comment: You might be interested in path finding algorithms.

Comment: How long is your Entry list?

Comment: So could you use a inmemory database and use Spring repository?

Comment: The List is about 10k entries. Maybe inmemory is a solution, I don't know.

Comment: Could not you just create separate Map for each search criteria(key = searchCriteria). On every search, take appropriate map and do get from map. Code would look like `searchByOrigin.get("berlin")` ?

Answer (score 1):

Guava's Multiset or Multimap implementations might come in handy:

https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained

Even better, apache JXpath:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/

Comment: jxpath is interesting, but as far as I read it just executes the same `foreach` loop that I wrote above. So no caching... `Multimap` looks promising, maybe I could then cache the search result in a multimap after evaluation, and discard the cache on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Java8? If so, a stream should be able to do that (I have just filtered for the origin, but the example can be expanded to all fields...):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Combinations {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 

        List<Entry> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Entry("berlin", "newyork", sdf.parse("2017-10-10")));
        list.add(new Entry("berlin", "london", sdf.parse("2017-10-10")));
        list.add(new Entry("sydney", "barcelona", sdf.parse("2017-10-10")));

        System.out.println(list);

        String filterOrigin = "berlin";

        System.out.println(list.stream().filter(e -> e.getOrigin().equals(filterOrigin)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}

class Entry {
    private String origin;
    private String destination;
    private Date date;
    public Entry(String origin, String destination, Date date) {
        super();
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.date = date;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entry [origin=" + origin + ", destination=" + destination + ", date=" + date + "]";
    }
    public String getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }
    public void setOrigin(String origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }
    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }
    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

Comment: This would probably be the best solution if I want to run the filter on each search request. But I'd prefer a caching solution.

Comment: Can't you just cache the results in a Map with the key an object containing the search parameters und the value being the results?

Comment: That's also a nice suggestion. You mean like `map.put("origin=berlin", entry);`

Comment: Actually, it would be even better to have a Map<String, List<Entry>> to have fast access to the search result.